# Disable author names in the bottom line of my LaTeX slides

Tags: beamer, titles

In my presentation with LaTeX slides the author name appears in the bottom line of every slide. Is there a way, to disable the appearance of the name in the bottom line, whereas I want to put the names as

```
\author{...}
```

so that it appears on the title page?

So to ask it in another way: is there a command to just disable the output of the author name in the bottom line?

---

Preamble:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\title{....}
\author{....}
\date{\today}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\beamersetuncovermixins{\opaqueness<1>{25}}{\opaqueness<2->{15}}
\begin{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  This will also serve as a test case and ensure that the solution actually works for you.

Comment: You need to be more specific. "LaTeX slides" doesn't mean much on a LaTeX website. All slides here are LaTeX slides ;-) (Except such which are made with ConTeXt or plain-TeX, of course). Please tell use which class (e.g. `beamer`) and which style/theme you are using. Posting a full minimal working example (MWE) which shows your preamble and an example slide would be even better.

Comment: \documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\title{....}
\author{....}
\date{\today}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}

\beamersetuncovermixins{\opaqueness<1>{25}}{\opaqueness<2->{15}}

\begin{document}

Comment: So that is my preamble - I want to put my name into the author bracket, but I don't want it to appear in the bottomline

Answer (score 24):

If you perhaps are using the `beamer` class you can adopt this approach:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\title{My title}
\institute{My institute}
\author[]{Made by:\\Author name} %<= used the short author name [] for the footline: leave it blank to not displayed

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title}
example text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which gives you two frames: in the titlepage, the author will be displayed while in the rest of the presentation no.

[image]

[image]

> **EDIT**

Since you reported in a comment your preamble I can edit my answer. Some remarks on the preamble: I think you can avoid to say `\usepackage{verbatim}` (in my example I will insert an example of text inside the `verbatim` environment without loading the package) and instead of customizing your theme with `\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}` you can select themes with `\usetheme` (for a detailed list, see [the Beamer Theme Matrix](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix)).

To remove the author, the approach is the same as explained before.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer} 
\usepackage{lmodern}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{} %<= to suppress the headline otherwise section and subsection will be displayed in the navigation bar
\beamersetuncovermixins{\opaqueness<1>{25}}{\opaqueness<2->{15}} 

\title{My title}
\institute{My institute}
\author[]{Author name} %<= used the short author name [] for the footline
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Title}
\begin{verbatim}
example of text in verbatim environment
\end{verbatim}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The output are the following two frames:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Glad of having helped you. :)

Comment: @maad: If my answer is fully answering the question, you might consider to accept it by clicking the green tick below the voting arrows.