# Remove author and institution in footline

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I am writing a beamer presentation using the CambridgeUS theme but my presentation has multiple authors and their names do not fit in the footline at the author section. I want to delete all of their names so that they do not appear at all. Also I do not want the institution name to appear either.

How can I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\author[]{Author name} %<= used the short author name [] for the footline` from Claudio's answer [Disable author names in the bottom line of my LaTeX slides](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58223/15717)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [texenthusiast](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15717/texenthusiast), said in the comment, the simplest thing to do is to use the optional arguments of `\author` and `\institute` commands and let them be empty.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\title{My talk}
\author[]{Author 1, Author 2, Author 3}
\institute[]{My university}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{One}
\subsection{One one}
\begin{frame}{Title}
Some text
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

The title page:

[image]

The first frame:

[image]

Comment: I made the changes you told me and I do not have the authors or the institute in the footline. However, the brackets from the institue still appear; this is my code: \begin{document} \setbeamercovered{transparent}
\title{Title}\author[]{Author 1\\Author 2\\Author 3\Author 4\\}\institute[]{Institute}\frame{\titlepage}
\frame{\tableofcontents}\section{Comparison}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Technology and Language}
\end{frame}\end{document}

Comment: @Jessy09: did you try with the code I put in the answer? With that code I don't have any bracket as it is possible to see from te images. Perhaps this happens because we're running different Beamer versions (mine is the one from an updated TeXLive 2012). Which distribution do you use?

Comment: I am using the distribution TeXLive 2009 and that's probably why it doesn't work. I changed the theme because I don't have time to update the distribution especially since I am using Ubuntu. Thank you for your answer