# Beamer: Showing only page number in footer and not the frame page number (Warsaw theme)

Tags: beamer

By default, the Warsaw theme in Beamer shows author's name, presentation title, and page number in the footer. How can I only show the page number in the bottom right corner of the footer?

My current LaTeX code is shown below:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage[hang,footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=white}
\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]

\title{Beamer title}
\author{Author name}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

My current output looks like this:

[image]

but I'd like to disable "Author name" and "Beamer title".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usetheme{Warsaw}

%\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber] % Removed
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[framenumber] % Added

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58219
\title[]{Beamer title} % Modified (added empty optional argument [])
\author[]{Author name} % Modified (added empty optional argument [])

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Test   
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Found here [slide numbering in Beamer class (Warsaw theme)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8179) after searching for `beamer change page number Warsaw` in Google.